# Android Notification without click event?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I would like to try and make a Notification that does not respond to a click. Is this possible? i.e. when it is visible in the Notification area, and the user touches it, I want "nothing" to happen.

This is different to a normal Notification - when it is visible, and the user touches it, the Notification Area hides, and the Intent is launched. I do not want the Notification Area to hide when it is touched.

---

I can make one that doesn't launch an activity:

- [Possible to make an Android Notification that does not call an Intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779571/possible-to-make-an-android-notification-that-does-not-call-an-intent)
- [Android - notification manager, having a notification without an intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040742/android-notification-manager-having-a-notification-without-an-intent)

But it still responds to a click, by hiding the notification bar again (i.e. standard expected behaviour).

---

This question is a duplicate of [How to disable a click event of notification in android development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805935/how-to-disable-a-click-event-of-notification-in-android-development) but that question does not have an answer. (if there is a better way to ~bump~ that question up again, I will do that & delete this question)

---

Note: I know this is not "the Android way", but it is still something I would like to try.

Comment: Actually , what are you wanted to do ? Explain it more elaborately .....

Comment: @Junaid - question updated thx.

Comment: I think you can show your own custom notification using popupwindow in your app. You can define how that popupwindow will behave with user ineractions.

Comment: @Junaid - I wish to use an `android.app.Notification` that will appear in the standard Notification Area; not to use a popup window. thx

Comment: Hmm .... I will let u know if i come up with something that might help you. Till then , best of luck with the solution of your problem, Thanks....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do not want the Notification Area to hide when it is touched.

That would require firmware modifications. You are not in control over the notification area; the OS is.

Answer (score 4):

Use Intent intent = new Intent() and insert this into the PendingIntent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried

```
new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!")
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
    // Set the intent null or empty and autoCancel false
    .setContentIntent(null)
    .setAutoCancel(false);
```

For more info about **setAutoCancel()** check [Android Document](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) here.